# How to tell if it's your first run?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I wonder how I can check whether it's the first run of my ios app, in order to start with a specific view.
I saw many ways to do with Objective-C, but not how to implement it in Xamarin.

Comment: How about reading a file your app creates? If it's there it's not your first run, otherwise you just create it.

Comment: Are you sure you can't translate one of the techniques you've seen in Objective-C to the Xamarin environment?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Xamarin, but this sounds as easy as checking the existence of a custom entry, say `LaunchedBefore`, in `NSUserDefaults` at the app launch and writing it if not found.

Something like

```
public override void FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application) {
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
    const string key = "LaunchedBeforeKey";
    if (!defaults.BoolForKey(key)) {
        // First launch
        user.SetBool(true, key);
        defaults.Synchronize();

        // Do stuff specific to the first launch here...
    }

    //...
}
```

I'm using `"LaunchedBefore"` as opposed to `"FirstLaunch"` since `BoolForKey()` will return `false` in case the key doesn't exist, so it's semantically better this way.